# Filter array with multiple startsWith and endsWith arguments

Tags: javascript

Browsed several different questions/answers surrounding this question, but most rely on `includes` or `indexOf`

Problem: How any array to filter (`names` in this case). I need to filter it using 2 different arrays, one of which has `startsWith` criteria and the other has `endsWith` criteria

```
var names = ['BOB','CATHY','JAKOB','AARON','JUSTICE','BARBARA','DANIEL','BOBBY','JUSTINE','CADEN','URI','JAYDEN','JULIE']
startPatterns = ['BO','JU']
endPatterns = ['EN','ICE']

//res = ['BOB','JUSTICE','JUSTINE','JULIE','JAYDEN','JUSTICE']
```

Obviously you cannot do `names.filter(d => d.startsWith(startPatterns))` because `startPatterns` is not a string but a array. Something like this isn't working and is terrible slow too:

```
res=[]
names.forEach(d => {
  endPatterns.forEach(y => d.endsWith(y) ? res.push(d) : '')
  startPatterns.forEach(s => d.startsWith(s) ? res.push(d) : '')})
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Your code works, it just has problems with duplicates. An easier way is to `names.filter(name => startPatterns.some(p => name.startsWith(p)) || endPatterns.some(p => name.endsWith(p)));`

Comment: `forEach` does not return anything, so the usage of an expression bodied function and there a misappropriation of `?:` to `push`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.some` on the pattern arrays to achieve this:

```
let filtered = names.filter(name => (
  startPatterns.some(pattern => name.startsWith(pattern)) ||
  endPatterns.some(pattern => name.endsWith(pattern))
))
```

The logic here being "Return `true` if the name begins with at least one of the start patterns OR ends with at least one of the end patterns".

Comment: This works, but what if one of startPatterns or endPatterns is empty/null?

Comment: That wasn't part of the original question. What would your expectation be in either of those cases? You can use conditionals and/or default values depending on what you're expecting.

Comment: It would be something like this: `(startPatterns && startPatterns.some(pattern => name.startsWith(pattern))) || (endPatterns && endPatterns.some(pattern => name.endsWith(pattern)))`

Comment: djfdev is correct. Was out of scope for question. His answer is correct.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to say that wasn't a valid question. But I think the answer depends on what your requirements say should happen. The tip from @reg might work depending on this (i.e. only check the pattern array if it exists). But perhaps your requirements say that an empty patterns array implies that no name can be valid.

Answer (score 4):

You could build a regular expression and check the string against the pattern.

```js
var names = ['BOB','CATHY','JAKOB','AARON','JUSTICE','BARBARA','DANIEL','BOBBY','JUSTINE','CADEN','URI','JAYDEN','JULIE'],
    startPatterns = ['BO','JU'],
    endPatterns = ['EN','ICE'],
    regexp = new RegExp(`^(${startPatterns.join('|')})|(${endPatterns.join('|')})$`),
    result = names.filter(s => regexp.test(s));

console.log(result);
```

A non regular expression approach with an array with the methods and wanted values.

```js
var names = ['BOB','CATHY','JAKOB','AARON','JUSTICE','BARBARA','DANIEL','BOBBY','JUSTINE','CADEN','URI','JAYDEN','JULIE'],
    patterns = [['startsWith', ['BO','JU']], ['endsWith', ['EN','ICE']]],
    result = names.filter(s => patterns.some(([k, values]) => values.some(v => s[k](v))));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this will fail as soon as non-standard input is introduced, even something simple like `MR. ROB` due to concatenating into a regex - for that reason I'd prefer djfdev's `array.some` solution

Comment: @Klaycon, please see the second approach.